# R extract by mask keeps all the original number of cells

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to use extract by mask function in R. This is what I have done:

```
library(raster)
# download my shape file
shape <- getData('GADM', country='IND', level=0)

#download my raster file
rast<-getData('CMIP5', var='tmin', res=10, rcp=85, model='HD', year=50)
plot(rast)
```

[image]

```
#extract raster based on the shape file
dat<-mask(rast$hd85tn501, shape)
plot(dat)
```

[image]

As you can see, though the code works, my final raster is too small. If I type `dat`, it still shows that total number of cells is 1944000. What I want is to keep and display only those cells that I wanted to extract and the not the entire 1944000 cells.

**Edit:** I also tried this but it gives me some extra grids that I do not need (which `mask` was able to do).

```
raster::crop: plot(crop(rast$hd85tn501, shape))
```

[image]

Comment: Use `raster::crop`: `plot(crop(dat, shape))`

Comment: Thanks but it gives me extra grids that do not need. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: The first part was explanation; the code was just `plot(crop(dat, shape))`

Comment: And I suppose you could crop before/instead of masking if you like

Comment: Oh sorry. this does it. thanks